# Oracle 11g log file for finding details of an error occured in the past (ORA-00054)

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, locking

An error 'ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified' occurred last night in a TRUNCATE TABLE statement in one of our scheduled jobs. I need to find out which process and DML statement was holding the lock at that time. I know that we can check for any existing sessions which lock the object, but can we figure out the details for a past error from any oracle trace files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically you can do it by looking into v$active_session_history for queries that might potentially to lock your table in exclusive mode. Another theoretical way is to take a look into traces generated in bdump/udump directories of your server. The best way is to be prepared for the next time by event setup, that will generate trace in case this specific error will appear.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read this blog about [Diagnosing Locking Problems using ASH](http://oracledoug.com/serendipity/index.php?/archives/1477-Diagnosing-Locking-Problems-using-ASH-Part-1.html) There is good info and demo's in there.